# working my way through a string, in R, by letter position

Tags: r, string, parsing

I"m working with DNA sequences for a class. In more general terms I find myself looking at oversized strings of letters with no commas or spaces or any signals of where to break them up.

I"m not sure how to import them.

But when I do I don't know how to work my way through a string in R by letter position.

If I want the first or last k letters, that's easy.

But what if I want each set of five consecutive letters from a long string separated out?

There is likely a function for that already. Any suggestion of what I need to lookup in the package library?

Comment: Do you want to extract overlapping consecutive letters?

Comment: Yes, the first five letters and the second five would have 4 letters in common.

Answer (score 4):

@MrFlick has a really cool piece of code that can handle things like this. If you want chunks of 5

```
x <- 'ACCACCACCCC'
m <- gregexpr('(?=(.{5}))', x, perl = TRUE)
regcapturedmatches(x, m)[[1]]

#         [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]    [,6]    [,7]   
# [1,] "ACCAC" "CCACC" "CACCA" "ACCAC" "CCACC" "CACCC" "ACCCC"
```

Or looking for specific patterns

```
m <- gregexpr('(ACC[CA])', x, perl = TRUE)
regcapturedmatches(x, m)[[1]]

#        [,1]   [,2]  
# [1,] "ACCA" "ACCC"
```

function ([source](https://gist.github.com/MrFlick/10413321)):

```
regcapturedmatches<-function(x,m) {

  if (length(x) != length(m))
    stop(gettextf("%s and %s must have the same length",
                  sQuote("x"), sQuote("m")), domain = NA)

  ili <- is.list(m)
  useBytes <- if (ili)
    any(unlist(lapply(m, attr, "useBytes")))
  else 
    any(attr(m, "useBytes"))
  if (useBytes) {
    asc <- iconv(x, "latin1", "ASCII")
    ind <- is.na(asc) | (asc != x)
    if (any(ind))
      Encoding(x[ind]) <- "bytes"
  }
  if (ili) {
    if (any(sapply(m, function(x) {is.null(attr(x,"capture.start"))})==T)) {
      stop("No capture data found (did you use perl=T?)")
    }
    starts<-lapply(m, function(x) {attr(x, "capture.start")})
    lengths<-lapply(m, function(x) {attr(x, "capture.length")})
  } else {
    if (is.null(attr(m,"capture.start"))) {
      stop("No capture data found (did you use perl=T?)")
    }
    starts<-data.frame(t(attr(m, "capture.start")))
    lengths<-data.frame(t(attr(m, "capture.length")))
  }

  Substring<-function(x,starts,lens) {
    if(all(starts<0)) {
      return(character())
    } else {
      return(t(
        mapply(function(x,st,ln) substring(x,st,st+ln-1), 
               x, data.frame(t(starts)), data.frame(t(lens)),
               USE.NAMES=F)
      ))
    }
  }

  y<-Map(
    function(x, sos, mls) {
      Substring(x,sos,mls)
    },
    x,
    starts,
    lengths,
    USE.NAMES = FALSE
  )
  y
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate along the length, making substrings as you go

```
str <- paste(letters, collapse = "")
sapply(seq(nchar(str)-5), function(i) substr(str, i, i+4))
#  [1] "abcde" "bcdef" "cdefg" "defgh" "efghi" "fghij" "ghijk" "hijkl" "ijklm"
# [10] "jklmn" "klmno" "lmnop" "mnopq" "nopqr" "opqrs" "pqrst" "qrstu" "rstuv"
# [19] "stuvw" "tuvwx" "uvwxy"
```

And, using `stringi` this is much faster for large strings

```
library(stringi)
inds <- matrix(c(seq(nchar(str)-5), seq(nchar(str)-5)+4), ncol=2)  # indices of substrings
stri_sub(str, inds)
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew if had to be a pretty fundamental question. I just didn't know the right camand and wasn't coming up through it via help in R studio.

Answer (score 1):

The [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org) [Biostrings](http://bioconductor.org/packages/Biostrings) package is designed to work with DNA sequences.

```
library(Biostrings)
dna = DNAString(paste(sample(c("A", "C", "G", "T"), 10000, TRUE), collapse=""))
Views(dna, seq_len(nchar(dna) - 5), width=5)
```

leads to

```
> Views(dna, seq_len(nchar(dna) - 5), width=5)
  Views on a 10000-letter DNAString subject
subject: CAGTAGGGCAATTGCTGTCGAATCATCAGTCGGG...CCAACTATAAACAAAAATTAGAAACCACCAGCGA
views:
       start  end width
   [1]     1    5     5 [CAGTA]
   [2]     2    6     5 [AGTAG]
   [3]     3    7     5 [GTAGG]
   [4]     4    8     5 [TAGGG]
   [5]     5    9     5 [AGGGC]
   ...   ...  ...   ... ...
[9991]  9991 9995     5 [CCACC]
[9992]  9992 9996     5 [CACCA]
[9993]  9993 9997     5 [ACCAG]
[9994]  9994 9998     5 [CCAGC]
[9995]  9995 9999     5 [CAGCG]
```

You could use `as.character()` to get a plain-old character vector, or continue to work with these in Biostrings.